# Can I access the "ME" contact in Windows Phone 7 (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, contacts, user-data

I would like to get my hands on some of the phone owner's details like their picture (The one appearing on their "ME" tile. Preferably as a Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact

Is this possible?
Cheers,
Fil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available via the public APIs.

If you want information from the user you have to ask them for it. The security principles behind the design of the platform prevent applications from accessing user data without them explicitly providing it.