# How do I get access to the user's Avatar?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

This might be a very basic question, but the words are so generic, that google is not helping me.

I want to access the picture of the user on a windows phone , which is the same picture provided in the "Me" Tile.

It doesn't seem to pop up in the PictureChooserTask.

How do I get that image, and does it have a url or can I only access the bitmap data?

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7899069/787202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xbox Avatar image url's:

- Small head shot: `http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/<gamertag>/avatarpic-s.png`
- Large head shot: `http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/<gamertag>/avatarpic-l.png`
- Full body shot: `http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/<gamertag>/avatar-body.png`

Here you can see them with my gamertag "Pedro Lamas":

[image: Small head shot]

[image: Large head shot]

[image: Full body shot]
<sub>(source: [xboxlive.com](http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/pedro%20lamas/avatar-body.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, is there any way on the Windows phone to know if the person is signed up with XBox?